# How can I change the javadoc class comment template in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I create a new Class the following javadoc comment is added

```
/**
 * Created by Dieter on 31.05.2015.
 */
public class Calculator {

    } 
}
```

The Problem here is that my name is not Dieter :D (yes, it is the (first)name of the OS-User).

I am looking for the template but all I can find online does not seem to work on the current version anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Preferences -> Editor -> File and Code Templates` and here you can edit your templates for new files.

You can read more [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html).

In IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.2 it works for me.

Comment: works, thanks! I've looked there before but i didnt see the different tabs! -_-